# C# Construct Object with Object Type Properties as default

Tags: c#

let's say I have this :

```
public class University
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public Adress Adress { get; set; }
    public Countings Countings { get; set; }
}

public class Adress
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Postalcode { get; set; }
}

public class Countings
{
    public int studentCount { get; set; }
    public int profCount { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to have a new object of University with all properties with their default value:

```
var university = new University();
```

How can I make sure that the properties Adress and Countings are also constructed and not just null ?

Regards !

Comment: Give them a default value? Or write a parameter-less constructor that initializes them with a default

Answer (score 4):

Set them with initializers. You can do this in the default constructor, but it's usually easiest to do it in the property's declaration:

```
public class University
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public Adress Adress { get; set; } = new Adress();
    public Countings Countings { get; set; } = new Countings();
}

public class Adress
{
    public string Street { get; set; } = "";
    public string City { get; set; } = ""
    public string Postalcode { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Note that Value Types (like `int` already have a default that cannot be null), so unless the default value for `studentCount` or `profCount` is something other than `0`, it's not necessary to initialize those properties. They will automatically default to zero.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
public class University
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public Adress Adress { get; set; } = new Adress();
    public Countings Countings { get; set; } = new Countings();
}
```

You could also init them in a ctor:

```
public class University
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public Adress Adress { get; set; }
    public Countings Countings { get; set; }

    public University()
    {
        this.Adress = new Adress();
        this.Countings = new Countings();
    }
}
```